# What is the relationship between the normal and the t-distribution in R (pt and pnorm)?

Tags: r, distributions, normal-distribution

In R, is it true that:

`pt(q,df=Inf)`  $=$ `pnorm(q)`?

Or in words, can I supply `df=Inf` in the cummulative t-distribution to get to the standard normal distribution function in R, as I should in theory?

Comment: Why don't you try ? :-/

Comment: For which `q` do you suggest trying and how should I suggest accuracy? Mostly a rhetorical question, see answer by Martin below.

Comment: Thus you are more convinced by an answer claiming Yes/No without demonstration than trying for a sample of `q` values ?

Comment: You didn't seriously down-rate a legitimate question?

Comment: I am *not* the one who downvote. I'm sorry that he/she has not left a comment to explain his/her downvote.

Comment: I think it is OK to try, but my question was directed towards what R does in terms of code, which will give me an exact answer. A sample would always only be accurate to the degree of some approximation.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I was not adressing you in particular, I was more adressing the person who down-rated. Don't understand.

Comment: I think he/she downvoted because your question does not show research efforts. I agree this does not justify a negative score (+1 for compensation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the `R` source code for the internal `pt` function:

http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/pt.c

The relevant code snippet is

```
if(!R_FINITE(n))
    return pnorm(x, 0.0, 1.0, lower_tail, log_p);
```

In other words, `pt` automatically detects an infinite degrees of freedom parameter and calls `pnorm`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In fact the implementation of the t-distribution in R detects this special case, and simply calls the relevant functions for the normal distribution.